# Excel - Stockhistory + VSTACK

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula, lambda

I am working on STOCKHOSTORY function to pull stock data of 50+ stocks/tickers ; then i am trying to put them into power query. Issue 1: Every stock history array is placed after certain interval of columns eg: A:D , E:H ...

I have thought of using VSTACK (to put them one below other and then easily importing to PQ) but i am not sure how to vstack different array without hardcoding all arrays in 1 formula. Can we use LAMBDA recursive to achieve the same?

Image of arrays
[image: I have added an image of arrays]

This is with the VSTACK formula
[image: This is with the VSTACK formula]

```
STOCKHISTORY(A1,TODAY()-10,TODAY(),0,1,0,1,2,3,4)

VSTACK(A2#,G2#,M2#,S2#,Y2#)
```

Comment: Do you have a bit of sample data with expected results? `TOCOL()` might work here, or otherwise there is a construct using `REDUCE()` to `VSTACK()` different arrays by looping over them.

Comment: @JvdV I have added an image of arrays in the main question, please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `REDUCE` for this:

```vb
=LET(shares,A1:A3,
λgetStockData,LAMBDA(a,STOCKHISTORY(a,TODAY()-10,TODAY(),0,1,0,1,2,3,4)),
DROP(IFERROR(
    REDUCE("",shares,LAMBDA(result,share,VSTACK(result,share,λgetStockData(share))))
,""),1))
```

[image]

I put the relevant shares in A1:A3.

Comment: Nice. You could use`TOCOL(1:1,1)` for `shares` to use data as posted by the topic starter.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my personal spin to what you are after:

[image]

Formula in `A3`:

```
=DROP(UNIQUE(REDUCE("",TOROW(1:1,3),LAMBDA(x,y,IFNA(VSTACK(x,HSTACK("Exchange\Stock",STOCKHISTORY(y,TODAY()-10,TODAY(),0,1,0,1,2,3,4))),y)))),1)
```

Comment: Nice use of unique to not have the header repeat itself within the data.

Comment: I have not tried this, as i did not understand it plus the answer by @P.b worked well

Comment: Well you could still take the time to at least try it out and feedback. Somebody took time and effort to help you where you asked for help. On top of that, my TOCOL comment is "stolen" from this formula by JvdV.